# Are there any best practices on upper limits how frequently to run an INSERT?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

An application has the requirement to store data in a simple DB (single table likely, fewer than 10 fields). Data is acquired by polling a remote service about at about 10Hz, we might get a handful of rows each poll.

The application and DB will be on servers used by other products so while it doesn't need to be super-performant, it mustn't cause serious degradation to other applications or hog resources.

How frequently is it advisable to make SQL INSERTs? Is tens or hundreds of INSERTs per second reasonable or is it considered preferable to batch, maybe once per second or every several seconds? Are there any common practices? DBs aren't my main area so the overhead of individual calls (c#) code->DB (MSSQL) isn't something I know anything about.

Comment: Bulk insertion always gives better performance over the individual. At the same time reduce the transaction scope and tracking in C# too.

Comment: I would write them to an internal concurrent queue.  Have another thread pull all records from the queue, start a transaction, do the inserts, then commit every interval. It'll be easier on the database, and won't hang up whatever it is you are trying to do in your polling routine.  You can easily change the interval to whatever is best, 1 second, 5 seconds, 30 seconds... And it SHOULD scale as the system gets more loaded, it will actually become more efficient.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I was thinking about this approach trying to decide if it was needed, or just fun to code :) Possibly using producer/consumer implementations in .Net to learn how they work

Comment: Be VERY careful that you are not prematurely optimizing. And be VERY careful about trying to throttle your application. When you delay or queue your DB updates, you will likely need to implement much more sophisticated error handling.

Comment: @SMor well there's optimizing an there's bad design :) But yes this is always good advice.

Answer (score 0):

In general, running an `insert` ten times is more expensive that running one insert for 10 rows. There are basically two reasons:

- There is overhead for each transaction. 10 transactions have 10x overhead.
- There is overhead for running a query. 10x queries have 10x overhead.

(The second is mitigated if the query plan is cached, but even so, looking up the plan in the cache is overhead.)

That said, SQL Server on reasonable hardware should be able to handle tens and probably hundreds of inserts per second. If that meets your application requirements, then no both in changing them.

If it doesn't, you can start working on optimizations, such as caching inserts on the application side so you can do larger volume inserts. No doubt, there are tools/libraries on the application side that can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the following approaches expressed in pseudocode:

First approach:

```
For each remote service polling
  start transaction
  if the number of rows < bulk copy threshold
     send all inserts in single batch
  otherwise
     bulk copy rows     
  end if
  commit transaction
end for
```

bulk copy threshold is the number of rows from which is more efficient to use bulk copy than a batch of inserts.

to bulk copy rows there is a specialized class [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) that is the most efficient inserting many rows.

If the first approach cannot handle the many rows that are coming, you can use the following second approach.

```
loop 
  while (batch.rows < batch size) and (time elapsed since last bulk copy < batch interval)
    add rows to batch from web service
  end while

  start transaction 
  bulk copy batch
  commit transaction
  clear batch
end loop
```

batch size and batch interval are numbers that you need to adjust.

First approach gives you the lowest latency. As soon as the data is fetched from the remote web service it is inserted on SQL Server. But might be the case that it cannot handle the many rows that are comming.

Second approach has greater latency, however it can handle much more rows.

Second approach could be improved. Instead of waiting to fill the batch or interval expires to send the data to SQL Server you can send the rows to SqlBulkCopy continously. It can be achieved by implementing an IDataReader from remote sevice polling. The DataReader would have an internal buffer (a queue) filled from the last call to remote web service. When interval elapses or batch size is reached and there in no more rows in the queue DataReader.Read() returns false. If there is no more rows in the queue but interval is not elapsed or batch size is not reached, the DataReader calls the remote web service again to the fill the internal queue.

This refinement has some advantages:

- Consume much less memory. You don't need to keep the entire batch in memory, only the internal queue, just a few rows.
- It is sending rows to SQL Server as they come. You don't need to wait to fill the batch to send it to SQL Server.
- It can handle more rows per second.

Answer (score 0):

this is rather question of your needs, that for you need to considerate many options :

1. single row insert (generate overhead)
2. bulk insert (depending of your needs may no be aplicable)

If you are executing single row insert there will overhead, but also, you have better control of unique keys as an example
if you are executing bulk insert there is is lower control of data quality.

Common implementation I am doing is :

- bulk insert to temporary table
- processing data from temporary table to main table in chunks of 1000 records (you may test performance, that depend of server performance/usage but my tests in past give best result between 300 and 3.000 records)